# Scatterplot change color of specific point

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I am trying to create a scatter plot with quite a lot of points (>10000).

I want to highlight some of these points based on a certain condition by using a different color.
I know that I could accomplish this by iterating through the points and specifying the color individually, but I think that this will be very slow.

Ultimately I want something which looks similar to this:
[image]

I.e. Ideally I want to specify that the fifth point should be red.

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to accomplish this?

Furthermore, I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how I could add a legend to this kind of plot. E.g. that red dots mean "age>15" and blue dots "age<15"

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with this script

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
x = y = np.arange(20)
colors = ['k'] * 20
colors[4] = 'r'

ax.scatter(x,y,c=colors)
ax.scatter([],[],c='k',label='age < 15')
ax.scatter([],[],c='r',label='age > 15')
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

The output figure is

[image: output]

Comment: What are you doing with the color_map dict here? And also, isn't the solution somewhat highly constrained? I was thinking it would be simpler to just filter out all outliers from the data and perform scatter plot twice and be done with it

Comment: @sai I forgot to delete color_map, I was initially thinking using mpatches.Patch. I don’t see how this is constrained, all that has to be modified is the array of colors.

Comment: Ok. I know you have answred based on what OP has asked, but what I meant by constrained was in relation with manually picking/setting the 5th point to be red. I was suggesting something generic like this `ax.scatter(ages[ages >=15], c='r', label='age >= 15')`